# Converting string to float unsuccessful

Tags: python, floating-point, cs50

```
def main():
    x = abc_to_def(input("What time is it? "))
    if x >= "7.0" and x <= "8.0":
        print("breakfast time")
    elif x >= "12.0" and x <= "13.0":
        print("lunch time")
    elif x >= "18.0" and x <= "19.0":
        print("dinner time")
    else:
        print()

def abc_to_def(p):
    hours, minutes = p.split(":")
    if float(int(hours)) + int(minutes)/int(60):
        return p

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run the code in the terminal, everything is correct, but when I run check50 it says my output is "".

Comment: your function `abc_to_def` either returns `None` or whatever argument you pass into it. My question is why are you trying to compare strings, you can just remove the quotes `(")` and use the numbers directly.

Comment: `if float(int(hours)) + int(minutes)/int(60)` seems like a thought that was never completed.

Comment: Remove the quotes around the numbers and use `return float(int(hours)) + int(minutes)/int(60)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3


def main():
    y = input("What time is it? ")
    x = abc_to_def(y)
    if x >= 7.0 and x <= 8.0:
        print("breakfast time")
    elif x >= 12.0 and x <= 13.0:
        print("lunch time")
    elif x >= 18.0 and x <= 19.0:
        print("dinner time")
    else:
        print("no food")


def abc_to_def(p):
    hours, minutes = p.split(":")
    p = float(int(hours)) + int(minutes)/int(60)
    return p


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```